# Driver program for testing more than one function?

Tags: unit-testing, theory, software-design

I know the purpose of the driver program . it is to test one function from the original program you made  in order to find bugs.
But , can i test more than one function in the driver program ? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of testing, yes, a driver can test more than one function.  Infact they usually do.

A driver builds object(s) to be tested and calls their methods/functions and tests if they return expected results.  A driver is also sometimes called a suite of unit tests.

A driver's job is to exercise code.  Unit tests are a way to exercise code.  Drivers existed before the idea of unit tests so are a little more broad.

A unit test is supposed to be limited to some software unit such as an object.  There are other kinds of tests that a driver might run.  An integration test that proves code from different streams has integrated correctly.  An end-to-end test that proves that many objects and methods are working well together.

These other kinds of tests are easy to confuse since some people don't use their names rigorously.  "Driver" is an overarching term that encompasses them all that really means nothing more then that this code makes the code under test run so we can see what it does.